# how can I rename a folder using Matlab script

Tags: matlab

I want to rename a folder in a path by using Matlab script:

```
c:\My Path\New Folder\  -->  c:\MyPath\NewFolder\  %remove the spaces in the path name
```

got what I wanted finally to work:

```
system('7z e "C:\Public\test\dry?testing41013\Log?#1\max_logs_can_messages.tgz" -o"C:\Public\test\dry testing41013\Log #1\"')
```

had to use "?" for spaces in the first path but not the second path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MOVEFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) function. It works for folders as well.

```
movefile('c:\My Path\New Folder\', 'c:\MyPath\NewFolder')
```

Comment: my concern is that the content, in the folder, will be moved with it.

Comment: Yes it will. I just tested.